# Clarifying question on meaning of derivative of a linear transformation

Tags: real-analysis, linear-transformations

In my analysis class, my professor (and the textbook) reference the fact that $\mathbf{D}T(\bar{x}) = T$ for any $\bar{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ where $T \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n) $. I'm wondering about the precise meaning of this statement. Is it that the differential of any linear transformation is also linear? Or is that the differential of any linear transformation is *itself* (and therefore also linear)? The second seems confusing to me because the derivative of a function is often not itself. For example, $f(x) = 2x$ is a linear transformation but $f'(x) = 2 \ne 2x$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context the notation is slightly different than what you are used to.

Consider $f(x)=x^2$. In this notation the derivative of $f$ at the point $x$ acting on a vector $h$ is $(f')_x h = 2x h$. The derivative is the linear function $``$ Multiply by $2x$".

For $f(x) = 2x$ the derivative at the point $x$ acting on the vector $h$ is $(f')_x h = 2h$. Now the linear transformation is just $``$ Multiply by $2$".

Answer (score 2):

If you consider $T = 2$ as a $1\times 1$ matrix, then $f' = T$ as claimed. (the map is "take $x$ and multiply by $T$")

In general, if you consider
$$
f(x) = Tx 
$$

then $Df = T$, literally. You could check this by writing out the formula for $Tx$ in coordinates, then taking various partial derivatives of the various components to compute $Df$. In particular, the $i$th component of $Tx$ is

$$
\sum_j t_{ij} x_j
$$

and so 
$$(Df)_{ij} = \partial_j (Tx)_i = t_{ij}$$

as claimed.